# Secure App-Engine Backend with GCP API-Gateway and Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, jwt, google-cloud-api-gateway

My purpose is to secure my backend, which is deployed as GCP App Engine, with an API-Gateway, provided by Google, to only let Firebase authenticated users have access to it.

I set everything up, as stated in the [documents](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-firebase):

**API-Gateway config:**

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "PROJECT_NAME",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "firebase": {
      "authorizationUrl": "",
      "flow": "implicit",
      "type": "oauth2",
      "x-google-issuer": "https://securetoken.google.com/PROJECT_ID",
      "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com",
      "x-google-audiences": "PROJECT_ID"
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {
      "firebase": [ ]
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/hello-spring": {
      "get": {
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "operationId": "helloSpring",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-google-backend": {
          "address": "https://URI-TO-APP-ENGINE-SERVICE",
          "path_translation": "APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS"
          "jwt_audience": "API_CREDENTIALS_FROM_IAP_APP_ENGINE_APP"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "User": {
      "properties": {
        "creationTimestamp": {
          "format": "date-time",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "updateTimestamp": {
          "format": "date-time",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "uuid": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "x-components": {}
}
```

When I send a request - without a jwt token - to this api-gateways url, it correctly responds with

```
{
    "message": "Jwt is missing",
    "code": 401
}
```

**Firebase jwt**
"Default" firebase backend is used, no custom tokens are created. Firebase is used to create the JWT token. From the client following code snippet is used to receive a valid JWT:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
....

final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

final UserCredential authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

final String token = await _auth.currentUser.getIdToken();
```

But as soon as I add the JWT (*final String token* in code above), which is created by a firebase client app and add it to the request header with

```
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_CODE
```

gateway responds with

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Jwt verification fails"
}
```

The most detailed LOG I can see in GCP is:

```
response_code_detail: jwt_authn_access_denied{Jwt_verification_fails}
```

I also created a service account linked to this API-Gateway with following roles:

- roles/appengine.appViewer
- roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
- roles/run.invoker
- roles/apigateway.viewer

But still, the same error: "401 - Jwt verification fails". What am I missing,how can I see more details about this issue in GCP and what could be a solution?

Comment: Can you share how are you calling the API Gateway? You might use the wrong type of token.

Comment: The URI of the provided GCP API-Gateway is called with Postman. A GET request is sent and one header ist set: "Authorization" with value "Bearer JWT_TOKEN_VALUE". The JWT_TOKEN_VALUE is extraced from firebase.getIdToken. 
Even when I use the provided "Authorization" mechanism from postman and only set the JWT_TOKEN_VALUE, I receive the same error.
Or were you asking for another kind of information?

Comment: Is the call work without the security definition?

Comment: Yes it works without security definitions, just doublechecked. also verified it with your medium post (nice work).
As soon as I add security definition and security firebase I see 401: "Jwt verification fails" again and in the logs the error is "jwt_authn_access_denied{Jwt_is_missing}"

Comment: Regarding the config without security definitions.. I added "jwt_audience" to "x-google-backend" because otherwise api-gateway was complaining about "aud". I'm not sure but I think the issue is currently not about the above shown config?

Comment: I'm sending the firebase created jwt token. I'm not creating nor sending an idToken or something like that. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Yes, it could be the issue. Try to use a idToken created by Firebase. That's why I asked about the code that call your API Gateway (to check this!). Have a try and let me know

Comment: I just updated the question. Now you can see how the token is created. Because I'm using default firebase auth (no custom tokens / no custom backend for this purpose). I don't think that I have to use idToken. The idToken provided by firebase is not valid (because it only has the header and body part of the JWT and not the signature).

Comment: Why you're using the ID token in the Authorization header? Shouldn't you be using the access token instead?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere "firebase created jwt token" IS the 'idToken' of `getIdToken`; the access tokens are for service-to-service yaml flows. I am having [similar trouble](https://github.com/NickCarducci/mastercard-backbank-node-cloud-run).